# Diff between hours.minutes and hours.minutes

Tags: php, math

I have the following syntax:

194 hours and 45 minutes

```
$time[0] = 194.45;
```

45 hours and 12 minutes

```
$time[1] = 45.12;
```

so how to get the diff between $time[0] and $time[1] without a solution like

```
xxx hours and >60 minutes (xx.>60)
```

Comment: You can't. That's why we don't do this.

Comment: 194 hours and 45 minutes is 194.75 hours, there are 60 minutes in an hour, not 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$md = ((int)$time[0]-(int)$time[1])+(5/3*(($time[0]-(int)$time[0])-($time[1]-(int)$time[1])));
$diff = (int)$md.'.'.str_pad((int)(substr(strrchr($md,'.'),1))*3/5,2,0,STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

Given `$time` as defined in question, `$diff` will end with: `149.33`

Answer (score 1):

It makes very little sense to be using `.45` to store `45 minutes`. Why not use 2 variables, one for hours and one for minutes?

And why the restriction on the use of conditionals? You'll end up with ugly code like this:

```
 $time[0] - $time[1] - 
 0.40 * ( floor($time[0]) - floor($time[1]) - floor($time[0]-$time[1]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mins = array();
$hours = array();
foreach( $time as $k => $v) {
    $mins[$k] = round( $v - floor( $v), 2);
    $hours[$k] = floor( $v - $mins[$k]);
}

$diff = round( $hours[0] - $hours[1] + ($mins[0] - $mins[1]), 2);
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/2CfPWS):

```
array(2) { [0]=> float(0.45) [1]=> float(0.12) } // <-- Mins
array(2) { [0]=> float(194) [1]=> float(45) }    // <-- Hours
float(149.33)                                    // <-- Difference
```